# Updating Time second by second

Tags: android, time

I want my app always update time second by second and show it on other activity. I need the figures of the time and date to make calculation too. Can anyone help me? I tried this, but it only record the time once, i want it to update time by time. Thanks.

```
    package com.example.suntracking;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class TimeClock extends Activity {

    int timesec,timeminute,timehour,dateday,datemonth,dateyear,day,ampm;
    String daytext,ampmtext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        timesec = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        timeminute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        timehour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        ampm = c.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
        if(ampm==0){
            ampmtext="AM";
        }else {
            ampmtext="PM";
        }
        dateday = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        datemonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        datemonth += 1;
        dateyear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        switch(day){
        case 1:
            daytext="SUNDAY";
            break;
        case 2:
            daytext="MONDAY";
            break;
        case 3:
            daytext="TUESDAY";
            break;
        case 4:
            daytext="WEDNESDAY";
            break;
        case 5:
            daytext="THURSDAY";
            break;
        case 6:
            daytext="FRIDAY";
            break;
        case 7:
            daytext="SATURDAY";
            break;
        }
        savePreferences();
        Intent i= new Intent(TimeClock.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    private void savePreferences() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SharedPreferences savedata = getSharedPreferences("savealldata",0);
        Editor editor=savedata.edit();
        editor.putInt("timesec",timesec);
        editor.putInt("timeminute", timeminute);
        editor.putInt("timehour", timehour);
        editor.putInt("dateday", dateday);
        editor.putInt("datemonth", datemonth);
        editor.putInt("dateyear", dateyear);
        editor.putInt("ampm", ampm);
        editor.putString("daytext", daytext);
        editor.putString("ampmtext", ampmtext);
        editor.commit();
    }

}
```

Comment: Put timer in a separate function call that function in every sec by using Handler ..

Comment: But because i put this activity before the main activity, if i use timer and keep repeating here, will it get stucked?

Answer (score 0):

Download [this](https://github.com/jatinmalwal/demo-intent-service) demo project. It consists the use of Timer with proper ticking functionality. Ignore the rest Intent service.

Well for short here's the code :

```
final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (msg != null && msg.what == 100) {
            // Log.d(Constants.TAG, "What : " + msg.what);
            changeTime();
        }
        super.handleMessage(msg);
    }
};

// This is a timer just for ticking the clock after one second
Timer timer = new Timer(true);
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // There are two ways to make handler work done one by posting a
        // runnable or by handling the massages in onHandle method.
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(100);
        // or
        // mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        //
        // @Override
        // public void run() {
        // changeTime();
        // }
        // });
    }
}, 0, 1000);

private void changeTime() {
    date.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
    textView.setText("" + dateFormat.format(date));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. However, i need to use these time to do calculation too. Is it usable?

Comment: Yeah, but it get the whole time, i need to seperate the hour, minute , second and all for calculation. what can i do? can i combine your method with my code? If yes, can u tell me how?

Comment: Yes! You just need to combine your code with mine. You have the framework which is ticking time for you now just implement the logic. And please up-vote and mark the answer right it u think so.

Comment: To help others, please upvote and correct my answer if you thinks it deserves.